# MIPS question related lui and ori and li please

Tags: mips

```
li  $s0, 0x00220044
```

In MIPS, why does this command not possible ?? and

```
lui  $s0, 0x0022
ori  $s0, $s0, 0x0044
```

how does these two lines solve the problem?

Comment: It _is_ possible, so it's not clear what you're asking. Of course, `li` is a pseudo-instruction, not an actual instruction recognized by the processor. But that's true regardless of the value of the immediate, so there's nothing special about 0x220044.

Comment: As far as `lui` and `ori` are concerned, you can look up descriptions for both of those in _MIPS32™ Architecture For Programmers Volume II: The MIPS32™ Instruction Set_

Comment: As each MIPS instruction is 32-bits, and requires some opcode to specify what it does, there's not enough room left for a 32-bit constant.  In fact, in MIPS instructions, there's only room for 16-bit constants.  But by spreading a single constant over two instructions, we can reach 32-bits.